# Client-side JavaScript blog engine/script

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, client-side

Do you know any modern JavaScript blog engine or script which runs on client side? I am not talking about node.js, but rather a script which doesn't need more than static WWW server (i.e. no PHP).

It should:

- fetch blog posts from some JS database (e.g. localStorage, external JSON backend)
- render them using some HTML template
- allow to link to specific post
- possibly allow to edit posts and send them back to the database?

I know about JavascriptMVC, AngularJS, Backbone, Knockout, etc., but they are rather frameworks than complete apps. I'm searching for something similar to the old [JSCMS](http://jscms.sourceforge.net/eng/).

**Update:** Searching through GitHub I have found some desirable projects: [MiniLOL](https://github.com/meh/miniLOL) and [Static Site CMS](https://github.com/issackelly/static-site-cms). Do you know any more?

Comment: If there's no server-side component at all... where do you save the entered data so everyone can see it?

Comment: There could be an external server-side database from which the script reads stored posts, e.g. in JSON, and maybe sends them back using AJAX, but the script itself should run in the client's browser, so it doesn't use server-side technologies like PHP, node.js or Ruby.

Comment: That would mean the Javascript has full read/write access to that database, which means *anybody* has full read/write access to that database. To restrict that to admins, you need some server-side script which checks authentication. And there you're back at having a server-side component.

Comment: Not necessarily. The user can be authenticated prior to uploading the modified data, e.g. using OAuth 2. This is how Google Drive JavaScript client works.

Comment: For people voting for closing: Do you really think it's off topic? Why are you hindering solving my programming problem?

Comment: And for Oauth you need... a server-side component, otherwise there's nothing to authenticate against. For the record, I voted to close as *not constructive*. SO is not good for recommendations. If you'd have a concrete question on an implementation detail of such a system, that'd be a better fit.

Comment: @deceze: [OAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#clientside) doesn't require a server-side component and allows purely JS authentication. I'll do a research on my own and I'll update the question when I find relevant apps, for reference.

Comment: What you link to is the JavaScript way to authenticate *against Google's services*. Google is the server-side component here. Client-side only authentication makes no sense. If the entire code is running on the client, anybody can alter the code and bypass any authentication.

Comment: @deceze: This [example](https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html) successfully authenticates me using only client side JS, and after that I can e.g. save my modified posts to Google servers - this is what I'm talking about, I need a JS blog engine to talk to external services to store posts.

Comment: So you're basically just outsourcing your server-side component to Google? That's not in line with your original *"doesn't need more than static WWW server"* though.

Comment: Google or any other service would just be an external database for storing posts, I am searching for a blog engine which itself runs on static WWW server but I didn't write that it can't communicate with external backend. Anyway, I've found Static Site CMS, so never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do it but everyone would have to be on the same computer for the "blog engine" to work. It's almost equivalent to everyone using the same text document.

Comment: Why? Let's imagine you have access to a static web server, without any server-side scripting. You could store your posts in some external database having an REST/JSON API, but you want to have it fetched and rendered by some JS engine, which should also implement navigating between posts and so on.

Comment: Sure but you can't post without a post.